# To enable line wrap in syntax highlighter?

Tags: syntaxhighlighter

I would like to enable code line wrap in Alex Gorbachev syntax highlighter.
Read a [thread here](https://bitbucket.org/alexg/syntaxhighlighter/issue/182/version-3-making-code-wrap) to do it..

But I am not able to bring it into action.
Anyone knows how to?